# Processing Android connecting to Scanned network

Tags: android, processing

I am trying to write a small app that connects to a specific network from scan result but I get the error of "The global variable networkId does not exist" yet same code works when I use configured networks instead of the scan result.

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt;
import android.app.Activity;

Activity act;
Context context;
WifiManager wm;
List<ScanResult> results;
WifiInfo wifiInfo;
String networkSSID = "test";
String networkPass = "testtest";


void setup() {

    size(displayWidth, displayHeight, P3D);
    act = this.getActivity();
    context = act.getApplicationContext();
}


void draw() {
    textSize(height / 18);
    textMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    text("hello world", width / 2, height / 2);

    if (mousePressed == true) {
        wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        List<ScanResult> result = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult i : result) {
            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                println("Disconnectting from all networks");
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                println("Connecting to " + networkSSID);
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update1 :

So I tried some stuff but now I get an error that I don't understand at all...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 337489
Process: processing.test.wifi_list, PID: 30539
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at processing.test.wifi_list.WiFi_List$WiFiList.connect(WiFi_List.java:160)
    at processing.test.wifi_list.WiFi_List.draw(WiFi_List.java:84)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceGLES$RendererGLES.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1548)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1259)
```

new code :

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;


WiFiList wifiList;
ArrayList<WiFiListItem> wifiNetworks;
int fontSize;
String message = "Tap to scan";

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight, P2D);
  orientation(PORTRAIT);

  wifiList = new WiFiList();
  wifiList.init();
  wifiNetworks = wifiList.getItems();

  fontSize = height/30;
  textSize(fontSize);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
  noStroke();
}


void draw() {
  background(255);  

  fill(0);
  text(message, width/2, height/2);

  int currentHeight = 3 * fontSize;
  int barHeight = 5 + fontSize;

  // draw a bar representing the signal strengths for each network
  for (WiFiListItem item : wifiNetworks) {
    fill(200);
    float barWidth = map(item.level, -100, -10, 30, width);
    rect(0, currentHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
    fill(0);
    text(item.name + " : " + item.level, 10, currentHeight);
    currentHeight += barHeight;
  }
  // start scanning when the screen is tapped
  if (mousePressed == true) {

    wifiList.scan();
    wifiList.connect();
  }
}

// this function is called when the WiFiList object is done scanning
void wifiScanFinished() {
  message = "Scan Finished";
  wifiNetworks = wifiList.getItems();
}
```

WiFiList class

```
class WiFiList {
  protected WifiManager wifiManager;
  protected List<ScanResult> scanList;
  protected ArrayList<WiFiListItem> items;
  protected boolean bScanning = false;
  protected Activity act;
  protected Context context;

  WiFiList() {
    items = new ArrayList<WiFiListItem>();
  }

  boolean isScanning() {
    return bScanning;
  }

  ArrayList<WiFiListItem> getItems() {
    while (bScanning) {
    }
    return new ArrayList<WiFiListItem>(items);
  }

  void init() {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

    getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        println("WiFiList: scan finished");
        scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult networkDevice : scanList) {
          updateItem(networkDevice.SSID, networkDevice.level);
        }
        bScanning = false;
        wifiScanFinished();
      }
    }
    , filter);
  }

  void updateItem(String name, int level) {
    for (WiFiListItem item : items) {
      if (item.name.equals(name)) {
        item.level = level;
        println("[Updated] " + name + " : " + level);
        return;
      }
    }
    items.add(new WiFiListItem(name, level));
    println("[Added] " + name + " : " + level);
  }

  void scan() {
    if (bScanning) {
      println("WiFiList: already scanning");
      return;
    }
    bScanning = true;
    println("WiFiList: starting scan");
    wifiManager.startScan();
  }

  void connect() {

    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + "test" + "\""; 
    conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + "testtest" + "\""; 
    conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ "testtest" +"\"";
    conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for ( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
      println(i.SSID);
      if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + "test" + "\"")) {
        //here i only adapt your code

        println("Disconnecting from all networks");
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();  
        println("connecting to "+i.SSID);

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class WiFiListItem {
  String name;
  int level;

  WiFiListItem(String name, int level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
  }
}
```

Update2: Fixed the error by changing the wifi manager registration on void connect ( silly mistake ).

Yet the main problem still remains :D It doesn't connect to desaired network if its unknown

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are best answered by consulting the reference for the classes you're using. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) is the reference for `ScanResult`, which is what your `i` variable is.

That reference doesn't include a `networkId` variable, which is what your error is telling you. Please consult the reference to find the variable or method that you're looking for.

Comment: can you take a look now ?